# How To Monitor Total RAM Usage

Tags: c++, windows, ram

How would you get a value for total RAM usage?
Its for a GL graphics represantation of RAM usage.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/479722/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-c

Comment: it didnt work very well at all! Got an error: |24|error: 'MEMORYSTATUSEX' was not declared in this scope|

Answer (score 0):

You can use wmi to query system performance as shown answered here

[How to know the CPU and memory usage of a process with WMI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476018/how-to-know-the-cpu-and-memory-usage-of-a-process-with-wmi)

This is the recomended/ standard way to monitor perf in windows in general.