# Qt Application Perimeter

Tags: qt

I wonder what is the bounds of Qt's perimeter. I know for exemple that it can specify types (such as `qint` or `QString`), and I know it cannot get system informations such as CPU Usage or Memory Usage.

My question is about the limits of Qt.

Is it correct that Qt can only interact with what is inside the project but not with what is outside (I mean system-related) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get information about operating system with [QSysInfo](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7/qsysinfo.html) class, if you are looking for this. This is one example, I am sure there are other helper classes. I think you should use other libraries for information like CPU usage etc, see [here](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/17559) and also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479722/how-to-get-current-cpu-and-ram-usage-in-c).

Answer (score 0):

QT is nothing more/nothing less then a GUI C++ cross-platform framework. It's doesn't really have a perimeter, it has certain cross-platform functions implemented (like widgets/frames/controls a lot of other things). And within it's own functionality it provides (As being mentioned above) QSysInfo class, but you are free to add any OS dependent (if you target your application for particular platform) or cross-platform solutions for whatever tasks you need - hardware info/OS monitoring/etc..